# How can I use custom java library (from github)

Tags: java, github, import, hwpf

I want to use a custom library from github 
(https://github.com/ddoleye/java-hwp)

How can I import it and use it? 
I want to import and use the library in file_read.java file
[image: My system]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Normally, that library would have been [published on maven central](http://search.maven.org/), but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Instead, the GitHub repo includes directly the generated compiled classes (which is not the best practice)

That means you can clone that repo anywhere you want, and **[add a library](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project's_classpath%3F)** to your project, with the classes and sources referencing the folder you have used to clone the repo.

Answer (score -1):

On my end is use **InteliiJ IDE** and the process is quite easy when cloning a repository from Git hub

- main menu, **select VCS | Get from Version Control**, or, if no
  project is currently opened, **click Get from Version Control on the
  Welcome screen**.
- In the **Get from Version Control** dialog, specify the URL of the
  remote repository you want to clone, or select one of the VCS hosting
  services on the left.
- If you are already logged in to the selected hosting service,
  completion will suggest the list of available repositories that you
  can clone.

[image]

Comment: this doesn't answer the question